# Evitar que una tabla mueva sus columnas cuando aparece un scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

En esta imagen se puede ver que todas las columnas encajan bien pero...
[image: En esta imagen se puede ver que todas las columnas encajan bien pero...]

cuando aparece el scrollbar las colunas de la tabla de abajo no coinciden con las de arriba.
[image: cuando aparece el scrollbar las colunas de la tabla de abajo no coinciden con las de arriba.]

Si alguien sabe como evitar esto lo agradeceria mucho.

> HTML

```
    <TABLE border="1">
                    <TR>
                        <TH align="center" rowspan="2">Columna 1</TH>
                        <TH align="center" colspan="2">Columna 2,3</TH>
                        <TH align="center" colspan="2">Columna 4,5</TH>
                        <TH align="center" >Columna 6</TH>
                        <TH align="center" >Columna 7</TH>
                        <TH align="center" >Columna 8</TH>

                    </TR>
                        <TR>

                        <TH >Columna 2</TH>
                        <TH >Columna 3</TH>
                        <TH colspan="2">Columna 4,5</TH>
                        <TH >Columna 6</TH>
                        <TH >Columna 7</TH>
                        <TH >Columna 8</TH>                        
                        </TR>
</TABLE>
<div class="contiene_tabla">
<TABLE border="1">
    <TBODY>
        <TR>                
            <TD  align="center">Columna 1</TD> 
            <TD  align="center">Columna 2</TD> 
            <TD  align="center">Columna 3</TD> 
            <TD  align="center">Columna 4</TD> 
            <TD  align="center">Columna 5</TD>
            <TD  align="center">Columna 6</TD> 
            <TD  align="center">Columna 7</TD>
            <TD  align="center">Columna 8</TD> 
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
div.contiene_tabla {
height: 208px; 
margin-right: 100px; 
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
width: 100%;
}

table {
table-layout:fixed;
width: 98%;
}

th, td {
padding: 4px;
white-space: pre; 
/* CSS 2.0 */
white-space: pre-wrap; 
/* CSS 2.1 */
white-space: pre-line; 
/* CSS 3.0 */
white-space: -pre-wrap; 
/* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; 
/* Opera 7 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; 
/* Mozilla */
white-space: -hp-pre-wrap; 
/* HP */
word-wrap: break-word;
/* IE 5+ */
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código que tienes actualmente para las tablas?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que arriba se ve que ambas tablas coinciden porque estás forzando el tamaño de la tabla con `table {
table-layout:fixed;
width: 98%;
}` si eliminas este estilo podrás ver como se ve normalmente cada una de las tablas, de modo que al haber un scrollbar, el tamaño de la ventana cambia y por consiguiente el tamaño de la tabla.

Comment: Si elimino el estilo como dices lo que hace es que el ancho de las colunas se reduce a el tamaño del texto y tampoco cuandran este link es donde estoy haciendo mis pruebas https://jsfiddle.net/LuisDH/x6q0krat/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día, No había entendido completamente la pregunta.

Realice la modificación del código, sigo creando una sola tabla y en el css es donde especifico el diseño de esta, es decir, colocar el encabezado estatico. Saludos.

```css
table{
    border-spacing: 0;
    display: flex;
    max-height: 40vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 98vw;
    border:1px solid gray;
}

thead{
    background-color: #f1eee9;
    position: fixed;
}

th{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c0c9;
    border-right: 1px solid #c4c0c9;
}

th,td{
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 10.5vw;
    min-width: 10.5vw;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 3.5vh !important;
    padding: 4px;
    border-right: 1px solid #c4c0c9;
}
tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #edebeb;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="center" rowspan="2">column1</th>
            <th align="center" colspan="2">column 2,3</th>
            <th align="center" colspan="2">column 4,5</th>
            <th align="center">column 6</th>
            <th align="center">column 7</th>
            <th align="center">column 8</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>column 2</th>
            <th>column 3</th>
            <th>column 4</th>
            <th>column 5</th>
            <th>column 6</th>
            <th>column 7</th>
            <th>column 8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!--Importante definir cuantas columnas tendra la tabla -->
        <tr >
            <td colspan="8"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  align="center">Columna 1</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 2</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 3</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 4</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 5</td>
            <td  align="center">Columna 6</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 7</td>
            <td  align="center">Columna 8</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  align="center">Columna 1</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 2</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 3</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 4</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 5</td>
            <td  align="center">Columna 6</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 7</td>
            <td  align="center">Columna 8</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  align="center">Columna 1</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 2</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 3</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 4</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 5</td>
            <td  align="center">Columna 6</td> 
            <td  align="center">Columna 7</td>
            <td  align="center">Columna 8</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Si pero lo que busco tambien es que me encabezado quede fijo, por eso lo dividi en 2 tablas

Comment: Hola @LuisDonaldodelaOHidalgo realice la modificación de acuerdo a tu comentario, espero y sea la solución. Saludos

Comment: Oh si definitivamente es lo mas parecido muchas gracias @GustavoVilla.